# Power Automate Run History

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I created one Power Automate Flow. When I need to check Run History for my Flow I clicked on "All runs" and able to see all the History.

This history is only for 28 days, then after it automatically deletes by Power Automate. I need to create one Flow that automatically emails me that all history, which run in 28 days.

For that needs to create recurrence flow, but in that flow not found that Flow history. Is there any way to download or email that All History automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, out-of-box solution only enables you to manually download the Power Automate run history. If you want to download it on schedule, you may need to use 3rd party tools or create a custom solution.

Reference which may help:https://2die4it.com/2020/07/08/custom-connector-to-get-flow-run-history/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whole history if you call it via the PowerShell as far as I know, keep me updated if that works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).